# Magento File Paths Are Wrong

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've been having problems getting anything but index.php to work on Magento. Having finally got everything to execute I've not just got a simple problem where the urls to files are incorrect.

For example: the site is requesting

`.../static/version1111/.../logo.svg` which doesn't work.

`.../static/.../logo.svg` on the other hand does.

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: Magento URL Path error]

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this.

Current things attempted:

1)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /pub/static/ # <- Add This
```

This didn't work however completely deleting the .htaccess files in /pub/static made no difference either. Blow is the apache2.conf and .htaccess for reference.

conf:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride All
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# To avoid situation when web server automatically adds extension to path
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ## you can put here your pub/static folder path relative to web root
    RewriteBase /pub/static

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>

############################################
## setting MIME types

# JavaScript
AddType application/javascript js jsonp
AddType application/json json

# HTML

AddType text/html html

# CSS
AddType text/css css

# Images and icons
AddType image/x-icon ico
AddType image/gif gif
AddType image/png png
AddType image/jpeg jpg
AddType image/jpeg jpeg

# SVG
AddType image/svg+xml svg

# Fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType application/x-font-ttf ttf
AddType application/x-font-otf otf
AddType application/x-font-woff woff
AddType application/font-woff2 woff2

# Flash
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf

# Archives and exports
AddType application/zip gzip
AddType application/x-gzip gz gzip
AddType application/x-bzip2 bz2
AddType text/csv csv
AddType application/xml xml

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$>
        Header append Cache-Control public
    </FilesMatch>

    <FilesMatch .*\.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        Header append Cache-Control no-store
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresActive On

    # Data
    <FilesMatch \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/csv "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/zip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-bzip2 "access plus 0 seconds"

    # CSS, JavaScript, html
    <FilesMatch \.(css|js|html)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

    # Favicon, images, flash
    <FilesMatch \.(ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|swf|svg)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"

    # Fonts
    <FilesMatch \.(eot|ttf|otf|svg|woff|woff2)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

2)

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data VALUES (NULL, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

Result:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM core_config_data
-> ;
+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                                                             | value                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         1 | default |        0 | web/seo/use_rewrites                                             | 1                                                                                                                                               |
|         2 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url                                            | http://www.mymagento2.com/                                                                                                                      |
|         3 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url                                              | https://www.mymagento2.com/                                                                                                                     |
|         4 | default |        0 | general/locale/code                                              | en_GB                                                                                                                                           |
|         5 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_frontend                                       | NULL                                                                                                                                            |
|         6 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml                                      | NULL                                                                                                                                            |
|         7 | default |        0 | general/locale/timezone                                          | UTC                                                                                                                                             |
|         8 | default |        0 | currency/options/base                                            | GBP                                                                                                                                             |
|         9 | default |        0 | currency/options/default                                         | GBP                                                                                                                                             |
|        10 | default |        0 | currency/options/allow                                           | GBP                                                                                                                                             |
|        11 | default |        0 | general/region/display_all                                       | 1                                                                                                                                               |
|        12 | default |        0 | general/region/state_required                                    | AT,BR,CA,CH,EE,ES,FI,HR,IN,LT,LV,RO,US                                                                                                          |
|        13 | default |        0 | catalog/category/root_id                                         | 2                                                                                                                                               |
|        14 | default |        0 | analytics/subscription/enabled                                   | 1                                                                                                                                               |
|        15 | default |        0 | crontab/default/jobs/analytics_subscribe/schedule/cron_expr      | 0 * * * *                                                                                                                                       |
|        16 | default |        0 | sales/msrp/enabled                                               | 1                                                                                                                                               |
|        17 | default |        0 | carriers/tablerate/active                                        | 1                                                                                                                                               |
|        18 | default |        0 | carriers/tablerate/condition_name                                | package_value                                                                                                                                   |
|        19 | default |        0 | design/theme/theme_id                                            | 2                                                                                                                                               |
|        20 | default |        0 | design/head/includes                                             | <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}styles.css" />                                                          |
|        21 | website |        0 | connector_configuration/transactional_data/order_statuses        | canceled,closed,complete,fraud,holded,payment_review,paypal_canceled_reversal,paypal_reversed,pending,pending_payment,pending_paypal,processing |
|        22 | website |        0 | connector_configuration/catalog_sync/catalog_type                | simple,virtual,bundle,downloadable,configurable,grouped                                                                                         |
|        23 | website |        0 | connector_configuration/catalog_sync/catalog_visibility          | 1,2,3,4                                                                                                                                         |
|        24 | default |        0 | connector_dynamic_content/external_dynamic_content_urls/passcode | AfT5cYVO0dLTorxzzbUFPOPtTLryLILo                                                                                                                |
|        27 | default |        0 | dev/static/sign                                                  | 0                                                                                                                                               |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hasnt worked.

Thanks in advance

P.s
I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You need to update the .htaccess file under /pub/static folder. Open MAGENTO_DIR/pub/static/.htaccess and add the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /pub/static/ # <- Add This
```

Alternatively, you can disable static file signing by adding this record into the core_config_data table with this query:

INSERT INTO `core_config_data` VALUES (NULL, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
In this case, keep in mind that you have to flush the cache after executing the query.

I had the same issue and the second option worked for me.
Note: The original of this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759196/magento-2-cant-find-css-and-js-files)
All credit to Cristiano Casciotti

Comment: Not sure if I've done something wrong but I've attempted both of those and refreshed the cache and there doesn't seem to be any difference. I've added an image of the problem and the the data in the core_config_data table to the OP.

Comment: Ok so deleting the .htaccess in pub/static altogether seems to make no difference which doesn't seem right.

Comment: did you try  setup:static-content:deploy as well?

Comment: Fixed with sudo a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I hadn't properly enabled mod-rewrite. I fixed with:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Source: [Mateusz Papiernik](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

run this query in my sql

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

after that clear the config cache

```
bin/magento cache:clean config
```